# pandorafms monitoring

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, network-tools

I'm newbie for network monitoring. I'm using pandorafms 4.0.2 free version. I added about 1,167 agents and 5,831 remote monitors. unknown agent and unknown monitor level is high. number of unknown monitors/agent increase and decrease but it didn't reach to "0". i check few unknown monitors randomly and ping their ip addresses from terminal. result shows they are alive but pandorafms show them as in unknown state. i checked them after about 6 hours. but network lag is still in high value.need help.(I use ubuntu server)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe could be because of two reasons:

1. A lack of resources in the server. Normally a Pandora server can monitor 2000 devices but it depends on the resources of the server which hosts Pandora. You can [check the minimum requirements here](http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Installing#Minimum_Hardware_Requirements).
2. It could be a bug :-), in 4.x version a bug related to network monitoring was detected. This bug causes some random failures monitoring using ping.

I would update your installation to the new 5.0 version and if the unknown modules persists, you can check the problem of lack of resources by disabling some agents. Also you can check some tips to [configure Pandora for large environments here](http://wiki.pandorafms.com/index.php?title=Pandora:Documentation_en:Optimization).

Hope it helps.